# JMeter. How to add dependencies for variables in different requests?

Tags: dependencies, jmeter

I have request for logging users via JSON Body and .csv file such as:
JSON Body:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "email": "${user_email}",
    "password": "${user_password}"
  }
}
```

.csv:

```
load_testing_0000@example.com,load_testing_0000
load_testing_0001@example.com,load_testing_0001
...
load_testing_0004@example.com,load_testing_1999
```

And second request that has variable ${user_id} into the path `/en/api/v1/user/${user_id}/tickets?page=0&per_page=20`
which get data from another .csv file

```
699
700
...
2698
```

The request will be succesfull only when first user will be use path with first variable (699), second user with second variable(700) etc.
But now I have situation when first user can take second variable, and for example second user can take first variable. That's why my request has response code: 403 Access denied for current user.
How can I add this dependency (or implement this behavior using JMeter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to merge your 2 CSV files into one like

```
load_testing_0000@example.com,load_testing_0000,699
```

And configure CSV Data Set Config Variable Names section as:

```
user_email, user_password, user_id
```

So there will be a match between user email and user id.

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide to learn how to define and use multiple variables.

Comment: I understand what you say, but how I can use one .csv file in two different requests when in the first request I use only "user_email, user_password" values and in the second request I use only user_id value?